# MongoDB $cond with embedded document array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to generate a new collection with a field 'desc' having into account a condition in field in a documment array. To do so, I am using **$cond** statement

The origin collection example is the next one:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e8ef9a23e4f255bb41b9b40"),
        "Brand" : {
                "models" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "AA"
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "BB"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e8ef9a83e4f255bb41b9b41"),
        "Brand" : {
                "models" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "AG"
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "AA"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

The query is the next:

```
db.runCommand({
    aggregate: 'cars',
    'pipeline': [
        {
            '$project': {
                'desc': {
                    '$cond': {
                        if: {
                            $in: ['$Brand.models.name',['BB','TC','TS']]
                        },
                        then: 'Good',
                        else: 'Bad'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            '$project': {
                'desc': 1
            }
        },
        {
            $out: 'cars_stg'
        }
    ],
    'allowDiskUse': true,
})
```

The problem is that the **$cond** statement is always returning the "else" value. I also have tried **$or** statement with **$eq** or the **$and** with **$ne**, but is always returning "else".

What am I doing wrong, or how should I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$Brand.models.name` returns an array, we cannot use `$in` operator.

Instead, we can use [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) which returns an array that contains the elements that appear in every input array

```
db.cars.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "desc": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: {
                  $setIntersection: [
                    "$Brand.models.name",
                    [
                      "BB",
                      "TC",
                      "TS"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          "Good",
          "Bad"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "desc": 1
    }
  },
  {
      $out: 'cars_stg'
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nTBFyGXCAGj) | [Alternative `$reduce`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yMyfT2g06cD)